# How to partially clone a row

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which I have many columns.

With my current code, I clone everything from the last row.

```
 $("#tTable tbody tr:last").clone(true).insertBefore($("#tTable tbody tr:last")).show();
```

How can I modify this code so as to copy everything except the elements: **lList, cSpan and its children?**

```
<table id="tTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
                <select id="lList" class="listClass">

                <option value="0">(select here)</option>
                <span class="cSpan"><input title="custom" class="custom-combobox-input ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
                <a class="comboboxButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only custom-combobox-toggle" tabindex="-1" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text"></span></a>
                <div id="labelDiv"><label id="displayComboBoxText"></label>/div>
                <input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="">

    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use find selector to find `td of first` then remove it

```
 var row=$("#tTable tbody tr:last").clone(true).find("td:first").remove().end();
```

Comment: @AustinMullins now check i just use end funtion

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xJGa/)

```
var tr = $("#tTable tbody tr:last");
var trCopy = tr.clone(true);

trCopy.find("td:first").remove();

trCopy.insertBefore(tr).show();
```

The `.remove()` function (at least in jQuery 2.1.0) removes the selected element(s) as a side effect and returns the selection.

To empty the contents of the selected column without removing it, use `html("")`:

```
trCopy.find("td:first").html("");
```

Comment: Thanks, this removes the column completely.  I want to keep the column and remove its children